# Issues while cloning Attachment and changing owner through apex

Tags: apex

I have System Admin profile and before I did any change to code all things on the page are working fine, in clone code I did changes as I have to set attachment owner to current owner which is throwing the error if cloning oppy owner is inactive:

```
attachmentList.deepClone();
for(Attachment a : attachmentList){
  a.parentId = newOppy.Id;
  // I added following line then removed due to it is not working 
  // and throwing following error 
  a.ownerId = newOppy.OwnerId; 
}
```

> **Insufficient Privileges**
>
> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

Even after removed added line I am facing same error, not getting why this happening :( 
My question is :

1. Why I am facing this error?
2. How to change Attachment Owner if previous owner is now inactive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try marking your class as "without sharing"

Comment: Thanks PJC, This is the public class, no sharing applied on the class level

Comment: Did that fix your problem? Or aren't you able to mark it as without sharing?

Comment: No man, That cannot fixed my problem, but I just deleted the class and Visualforce page and copy pasted same code and recreate them, now it will working fine, I don't know what was the problem :(